# How to get arrays difference

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, difference

I have 2 multidimentional arrays.

Array1 containing some of available names:

```
Array1
(
[0] => Array
     (
         [quantity] => 13
         [idname] => 3
         [x_name] => Name-3
     )

[1] => Array
    (
        [quantity] => 5
        [idname] => 4
        [x_name] => Name-4
    )

)
```

and Array2 containing all of available names:

```
Array2
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_x] => 3
            [x_name] => Name-3
            [id_l] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_x] => 4
            [x_name] => Name-4
            [id_l] => 8
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id_x] => 5
            [x_name] => Name-5
            [id_l] => 7
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id_x] => 6
            [x_name] => Name-6
            [id_l] => 5
        )

)
```

Array1[][idname] = Array2[][id_x]
and
Array1[][x_name] = Array2[][x_name] (ofc...)

My desire output would be every elements from Array2 that Array1 does not contain... so:

```
Arraydesire
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_x] => 5
            [x_name] => Name-5
            [id_l] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_x] => 6
            [x_name] => Name-6
            [id_l] => 5
        )

)
```

I tryed with array_intersect but didnt work.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nested foreach loops. If the value from the current element of array2 is found in array1, remove the element:

```
foreach($array2 as $key => $value){
    foreach($array1 as $val){
        if($value['x_name']==$val['x_name']){
            unset($array2[$key]);
            $break;
        }
    }
}
var_dump($array2);
```

Live example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/eOOUi6

Comment: Thank's. Its realy helpfull!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at array_diff (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php),

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);

Array
(
    [1] => blue
)
```

failing that you might need to write a loop that runs through array2 and sees if its in array1, if its not add it to a new array and output that array

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr1 = Array();
$arr1[] = Array('quantity' => 13, 'idname' => 3, 'x_name' => 'Name-3');
$arr1[] = Array('quantity' => 5, 'idname' => 4, 'x_name' => 'Name-4');


$arr2 = Array();
$newTemp = Array();
$arr2[] = Array('id_x' => 3, 'x_name' => 'Name-3', 'id_l' => 4);
$arr2[] = Array('id_x' => 4, 'x_name' => 'Name-4', 'id_l' => 8);
$arr2[] = Array('id_x' => 5, 'x_name' => 'Name-5', 'id_l' => 7);
$arr2[] = Array('id_x' => 6, 'x_name' => 'Name-6', 'id_l' => 5);

$newTemp = $arr2;
foreach ($arr1 as $subArray1) {
    foreach ($arr2 as $key => $subArray2) {
        if ($subArray1['x_name']==$subArray2['x_name']) {
            unset($newTemp[$key]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
print_r($arr1);
print_r($arr2);
print_r($newTemp);
?>
```